# Master Worksheet Populate Rows on New Worksheet based on Picklist Field Value (Data Validation)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet, vba

I currently have a 'Master' worksheet with the following columns (reduced for simplicity)

- A - Data Type
- B - Name
- C - Object

The Data Type field has a Data Validation set so there can only be 10 associated values entered. There are 10 corresponding 'tabs' in my Excel workbook that are named according to these picklist values (so I have 11 total tabs, including the Master).

I want the workbook set up so that when a row is entered by a user in the Master worksheet, the information is also populated on one of the 10 worksheets, based on the corresponding Data Type value selected. For these non-master tabs, the data needs to fill the highest non-populated row on the sheet.  (E.g. If I have 50 rows on the Master, with 4 being Data Type'Custom Field', and I want to add a 51st row which has a Data Type of 'Custom Field', I want it to populate the 5th line on the 'Custom Field' tab, not the 51st line.)

Does anyone know if this is possible to setup? Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes this is very possible all you have to do is find the last row with data, then increment that value by one and use it to insert the new data into that row, use something like: LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 1

Comment: This is definitely possible, you can use `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` or `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`. Or! You can use a button that they can click once they've added the data into the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this would do it, (this would work well with a button):

```
Sub foo()
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Check how many rows of data on Sheet1
For i = 1 To LastRow 'loop from first to last row of Sheet1
    SheetName = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value 'Check the first cell for the name of the Sheet it ought to be copied to
    LastRow2 = Sheets(SheetName).Cells(Sheets(SheetName).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Check the last row of data on the sheet to be copied into and add one for the next free row
    Sheets(SheetName).Cells(LastRow2, 1).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value ' copy values from Sheet1
    Sheets(SheetName).Cells(LastRow2, 2).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value
    Sheets(SheetName).Cells(LastRow2, 3).Value = Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Xabier. I will try this sometime soon and report back!